# Message Box shows when loading new windows form

Tags: c#, try-catch, messagebox

I am working on a project that lists appointments, and allows the user to add, update, or delete a selected appointment.
When updating, and selecting the appointment to update, it opens a new window to make the changes.
I have a messagebox nested within a try-catch block, but it still pops up when the form loads.

```
private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //updates the type, but for all customers with same 
    //appointment type. Work in progress.
    MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(SqlUpdater.conString);
    MySqlCommand updateCmd = new MySqlCommand();
    DateTime startTime = startTimeBox.Value.ToUniversalTime();
    DateTime endTime = endTimeBox.Value.ToUniversalTime();

    updateCmd.Connection = c;
    c.Open();
    updateCmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE appointment SET type = @type, start = @start, end = @end WHERE customerId = @customerId";
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", typeBox.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", (DateTime)startTimeBox.Value);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", (DateTime)endTimeBox.Value);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", customerIdBox.Text);
    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    c.Close();

    try
    {
        if (appHasConflict(startTime, endTime))
            throw new appointmentException();
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (appIsOutsideBusinessHours(startTime, endTime))
                    throw new appointmentException();
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Appointment Updated");
                }
            }
            catch (appointmentException ex) { ex.businessHours(); }                
        }
    }
    catch (appointmentException ex) { ex.appOverlap(); }

    mainFormObject.updateCalendar();
}
```

On the main form and update button is clicked:

```
private void updateAppointmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (appointmentCalendar.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a row to update");
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateAppointment updateAppointment = new UpdateAppointment();
            updateAppointment.mainFormObject = this;
            updateAppointment.customerIdBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.customerNameBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.typeBox.Text = appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            updateAppointment.startTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            updateAppointment.endTimeBox.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(appointmentCalendar.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString());

            updateAppointment.Show();
        }


    }
```

The only instance of this messagebox appears within the try-catch block.

Edit: updated the try-catch to:

```
if(appIsOutsideBusinessHours(startTime, endTime))
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception occured. Please reschedule for normal business hours.");
            return;
            }
       if(appHasConflict(startTime, endTime))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excepetion occured. Appointment time is already taken.");
            return;
        }
       else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Appointment updated");
            mainFormObject.updateCalendar();
        }
```

But its still showing the appointment updated box on form load.

Comment: Kindly take a look on your Form_Load method , is there some code written there which cause this effect?

Comment: If it's not on the form load, make sure you are not calling `updateButton_Click`.... Also please add other code (maybe the load) because this would not be the issue.

Comment: Please post a [minimal example that reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is nothing in your question that would allow anybody to identify why a messagebox is shown when the form loads. Presumably this method is being called from somewhere on form load, but it's equally possible that you're calling MessageBox.Show() somwhere else. This will be very, very easy to resolve if you show us enough code to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, we're just throwing guesses at you.

Comment: It is off topic, but Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and this one is terrible. You catch teh same exception twice while not rethrowing it and apparently use a exception to communicate information. Here are two articles I link often on the mater: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Don't throw exceptions to control program flow. If you can detect the error (ie: `appIsOutsideBusinessHours(...)`, then you can have an `if` there to do something about it. There is no need for exceptions there.